# Correct MIME Type for .msg file download using ByteArrayResource

Tags: java, spring-boot, mime-types

I have a files stored in AWS S3 , and I do have a provision of getting hold of all the information of that file in one java object DocumentResult.

```
DocumentResult{
 
private byte[] result;
private fileName;
private contentType;
private String s3StorageId;

}
```

I have written a sample code to retrieve `byte[]` from DocumentResult and return a new `ByteArrayResource`.

```
@GetMapping("/get/s3-file/{s3StorageId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> downloadDocumentFromS3(@PathParam String s3StorageId) {

//Gets document from s3
DocumentResult storageResult = s3Service.getDocument(s3StorageId);

return ResponseEntity.ok() 
.contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(storageResult.getContentType()))
.header(Httpheaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"document;filename=testFile")
.contentLength(storageResult.getResult().length)
.body(new ByteArrayResource(storageResult.getResult()));

}
```

The code runs fine where `storageResult.getContentType()` yields MIME type `application/vnd.ms-outlook` but the document that gets downloaded has extension `testFile.vnd.ms-outlook`.

I am expecting  `testFile.msg` to be downloaded so that I can look at the email contents.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the `.msg` extension in the `Content-Disposition` header you're setting and use wrong `document`, instead of `attachment`:

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadDocumentFromS3() {

    //Gets document from s3
    DocumentResult storageResult = s3Service.getDocument(s3StorageId);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
         .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-outlook"))
         .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=\"testFile.msg\"")
         .contentLength(storageResult.getResult().length)
         .body(storageResult.getResult());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the suggestion did not work for me. What worked is removing filename from content-disposition and setting contentType=application/octet-stream.